# Autocert using gorilla mux

Tags: go

I want to generate certificate using autocert and using gorila mux, my actual code is:

```
func main() {
    certManager := autocert.Manager{
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        //HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("example.com"),
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("./certs"),            //Folder for storing certificates
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":https",
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate,
        },
    }

    go http.ListenAndServe(":http", certManager.HTTPHandler(nil))

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")) //Key and cert are coming from Let's Encrypt
}
```

my routers is:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))))
r.HandleFunc("/login.html",  LoginHtml)
```

How can I integrate the gurilla mux in my actual code?

Comment: [server.Handler](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.Handler) = r

Answer (score 3):

The integration would be like this:

```
func main() {
    certManager := autocert.Manager{
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        //HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("example.com"),
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("./certs"),            //Folder for storing certificates
    }

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))))
    r.HandleFunc("/login.html",  LoginHtml)

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":https",
        Handler:   r,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate,
        },
    }

    go http.ListenAndServe(":http", certManager.HTTPHandler(nil))

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")) //Key and cert are coming from Let's Encrypt
}
```

I would suggest to add some timeouts to the server. I usually go for Read, Write and Idle.